# How can I find a way to restart resume Firefox? It quit on me

Tags: firefox

I used to use Mozilla Firefox regularly. Yesterday it stopped working. I tried to use Internet Explorer to get help from Mozilla. When I did so, all attempts to download Firefox put me into a loop that goes me nowhere. When I click on the Firefox icon nothing happens.

Comment: By stopped working you mean it just doesn't load? Try locating the executable in your Program Files folder and running it. If the executable doesn't work then we know its firefox and not your shortcut. You may want to consider uninstalling firefox, restarting, and then installing firefox again. Could you elaborate on this loop you talk about?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Firefox's safe mode? Go to Start > Run and type `firefox -safe-mode`. You should get a dialog box asking you if you want to run in safe mode. Select "Start in Safe Mode". From there you can try to redownload it.

If safe mode does not work, try downloading the installer via FTP: ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/latest/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%2017.0.1.exe